# How to get Visual Studio 2013 to ignore {% tags %}

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I often do Python and Django development using Visual Studio.   Is there a way for the editor to ignore any tags that match this description?

Comment: do you use a python/django plugin?

Comment: Not a duplicate exactly, but this might have what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279/add-custom-tag-to-visual-studio-validation